# Print Pandas Series vertically aligned when printed with another string

Tags: python, pandas, printing, vertical-alignment, series

I have a Pandas Series, which should be printed with a string. The result of the following code does not look pretty.

```py
series1 = pd.Series({'a':1, 'b':2})
print(f"The series is: {series1}")
```

Result:

```
The series is: a    1
b    2
```

What I want:

```
The series is: a    1
               b    2
```

Would it be possible with a simple code?

```
print(f"The series is:\n{series1}")
```

May be a possible solution, but not perfectly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 15 spaces to the rest of the lines, not the first line:

```
s = series1.to_string()
line1, *rest = s.splitlines()
s = '\n'.join([line1, *map((' ' * 15).__add__, rest)])
print(f"The series is: {s}")
```